# Reason why reverse relation filtering fails when m2m field uses a string class?

Tags: python, django

I ran into a strange issue using Django 2.2 and trying to filter a reverse relation which was defined using a string reference to the class. The issue goes away if I pass the class itself, ie.

This FAILS:

```
class Whatever(models.Model):
   providers = models.ManyToManyField('Relation', related_name='dependants')
```

This WORKS:

```
from .relation import Relation

class Whatever(models.Model):
   providers = models.ManyToManyField(Relation, related_name='dependants')
```

Note the only difference is whether the m2m field is declared using a string or a model class.

When I have the foreign model as a string and I call:

```
Relation.objects.filter(dependants=1)
```

The error I get is:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'dependants' into field. Choices are: ...
```

None of the listed choices is `dependants`, basically it's not available.

This does work though:

```
r = Relation.objects.first()
r.dependants
```

Using an imported model class solves my specific issue but the advantage of using a string class to resolve circular dependencies is lost. In case this happens again can anybody shed light on why it might happen? Is it a known bug solved in later versions of Django or a known limitation of using strings to specify classes?

Note, I tried the following to resolve this:

- Simplifying both models so there were no special managers or other queryset hacks
- Fully qualifying the model name string, eg `'appname.Relation'`
- renaming both the field and the related_name in case of some internal conflict
- rebuilding and running migrations
- Changing the query to `Relation.objects.filter(dependants__id=1)`

Comment: Can you share your filetree? `from models import Relation` I am confused about this import are you just sharing a similar import or is this your actual import? (Also Django 2.2 is no longer supported please upgrade! I think there are even some known vulnerabilities in that version)

Answer (score 0):

I am tinking that your are getting this error because your two models classes are not in the same django app.
but you can steel using a string reference but you ought to use string dotted notation like 'app_label.model_class_name'

Comment: The models are definitely in the same app